# How to replace the values of string array from java in c using jni?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, arrays

This is my jni function in which I have to replace the values inside the array passed from java.

Please tell me how to do it.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_finals_Strpass_intake
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray dev){

    jfieldID myNamesID; /* store the field ID */
    int i=0;
    jstring myStr;
    char* myStr2;
    char* myNames[] = {"Hello "};
    LOGI("before class call ");
    // Get a reference to obj’s class
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
    LOGI("before id call ");
    myNamesID = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,cls, "myDevNames", "[Ljava/lang/String;");
    // Get the object field
    LOGI("before dev call ");
    dev =(*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env,cls,myNamesID);
    LOGI("before for loop call ");
    for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
        LOGI("before myStr ");
        myStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"gk");
        (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,dev,i,myStr);
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, dev, myStr, 0);
    LOGI("after release");      
}
```

Comment: i am doing it in c. and in c, there is no such function as in java

Comment: why is this question tagged as Java then, if you want to do this in C?

Comment: Because jni is a part of java and the output that i get has to be displayed in java ui.

Comment: So going back to my original comment, if you have the Strings available in Java and you want to replace the values with something else, then why is `String.replace` NOT a good idea?

Comment: because i have to replace the values inside c brother. i have to fetch the particular string array from java and replace its previous values based on the logic in c.

Comment: ` logic in c` - that's right, nothing to do with Java

Comment: @GokulKrishnan Please make a shorter code which actually compiles and show your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_contchar23914_CharArrClass_intake
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject job, jobjectArray ptr)
{

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,job);
```

myNamesID = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,cls, "arr", "[Ljava/lang/String;");

```
ptr =(*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env,cls,myNamesID);

for (i=0; i < len; i++) {

stringg = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, ptr,i);

    myStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,myNames[i]);

    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,ptr,i,myStr);
}

    (*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, ptr, stringg, 0);
```

}

Comment: dont forget to initialise the variables